# graphql client: map enum value to desired form

Tags: typescript, graphql-codegen

We are using `graphql-codegen` on both the client and the server to handle mapping from our graphql schema to our typescript types.

We have an enum in graphql

```
enum Status {
  ACTIVE
  INACTIVE
  NOT_CONFIRMED
}
```

On the server side of the equation I was able to make use of the `typescript-resolver` plugin to map on and off the internal values stored in the database.

I am struggling with the client side of the equation though, where we use `react-query`.
The documentation around `enumValues` is rather sparse; I have specified an `enumValues` in the config as so

```
overwrite: true
schema:
  - 'http://localhost4000/graphql'
documents: 'src/**/*.graphql'
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - 'typescript'
      - 'typescript-operations'
      - 'typescript-react-query'
    config:
      fetcher: graphql-request
      enumValues:
        Status: ../lib/model/Status#Status
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - 'introspection'
```

And when I look into the generated file it imports the `Status` in there. But when we actually run a query that contains the status field it is returning the serialized enum value instead (eg. "ACTIVE" rather than the mapped value of "active").

Answer (score 0):

In case you need all of your enums to stay consistent as they are in graphql schema (eg all caps etc), you can add this to the codegen config file)mine is `js` file, hence its object-like:

```
  config: {
    namingConvention: {
      enumValues: 'keep',
    }
  }
```